# nvcc(cuda)での静的リンクをつけてのコンパイル

Tags: cuda, compiler

gccにおける-staticオプションのような手法で，nvcc(cuda)で静的リンクをつけてコンパイルすることは可能でしょうか？
シミュレータ上でcuda-stream benchmarkを走らせたいのですが，シミュレータが動的リンクに対応していないため，nvccで静的リンクできる手法を必要としています．
コンパイルに使用するCUDA等のバージョンは問いません．
よろしくお願い致します．

Answer (score -1):

質問するときは最低限のマナーとして、環境（OS、ハードウェア、……）に関する情報を詳しく書いてください。

[技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#env)

具体的にCUDAの何を静的リンクしたいのかが明記されていませんが、CUDA 5.5以降でRuntime APIライブラリの静的リンクに対応しています。

[NVCC :: CUDA Toolkit Documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html)

> `--cudart {none|shared|static}`

質問する前に公式マニュアルくらいは目を通してください。

なお、Driver APIやcuBLAS、cuFFTなどは静的リンクに対応していないらしいです。

[CUDA 5.5の新機能(2): CUDA Runtimeの静的リンク - トータル・ディスクロージャ・サイト（事実をありのままに）](http://topsecret.hpc.co.jp/wiki/index.php/CUDA_5.5%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B0%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD(2):_CUDA_Runtime%E3%81%AE%E9%9D%99%E7%9A%84%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF)